# Single Email Alert with Multiple Queries in Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula

When we trigger an email through splunk we want to display 3 tables with different resultset. Is there any option to configure more than one splunk query to single email alert?

Please help with your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

you can crate a dashboard with these 3 tables and then publish that dashboard in an email. not sure  if dashboard can be converted in to an alert.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the approach here:

https://answers.splunk.com/answers/111602/trigger-a-pdf-via-the-command-line.html

You can create dashboard with many searches and graphs, schedule it with PDF schedule.

Then you can create a different shell script that runs the dashboard's pdf to email:

```
 !/bin/bash
  curl -k -u admin:password 
 https://localhost:8089/servicesNS/admin/search/saved/searches/_ScheduledView__mypdf/dispatch -d trigger_actions=1
```

After that you can set an alert that runs this shell scripts:

```
[whatever_alert]
 action.script = 1
 action.script.filename = whatever_pdf_trigger.sh
 cron_schedule = */10 * * * *
 dispatch.earliest_time = -2m@m
 dispatch.latest_time = now
 displayview = flashtimeline
 enableSched = 1
 counttype = number of events
 relation = greater than
 quantity = 0
 search = index=ops | head 2
```